# How to configure Resources filepath in Java

Tags: java

I having a java resource filepath as per this

```
http://localhost/Myapps/resource/style/style.css
```

However, due to having httpd to redirect my webpage to another server. the url has became

```
 http://localhost/httpdDomain/Myapps/
```

Hence, When using the httpd, I am unable to read the resources files. how can I configure the resource folder path to match as

```
http://localhost/httpdDomain/Myapps/resource/style/style.css
```

Comment: @Tinylss Hi. Would you please tell us Java framework used by you ? For example, Struts or Spring. This will clarify the problem.

Comment: try to adding style.css  into webapp directory